# Porting a cloudformation template to terraform

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-cloudformation

I am following a direction on Hashicorp's site regarding wrapping a CF Template in Terraform. There's a fair amount to the whole code, but the CF Template works, so the issue is with the "wrapping"...

Terraform plan gives me this error output:

```
terraform plan

Error: aws_cloudformation_stack.Momma: "template_body" contains an invalid JSON: invalid character 'A' looking for beginning of object key string

Error: aws_cloudformation_stack.Momma: : invalid or unknown key: source
```

So it seems that the "AWSTemplateFormatVersion" line is what it does not like. Hence the'A' it is picking up, I guess.

This is the Hashicorp page I am following, I'm wondering if there are any escape characters that are appropriate or, if anyone can see any immediate formatting issues with my JSON?

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cloudformation_stack

```
terraform {}

provider "aws" {
  version = "= 2.61"
  region  = "ap-southeast-2"
}

resource "aws_cloudformation_stack" "Momma" {
  source = "../../aws_modules/aws-db-event-subscription"
  name   = "Momma-Stack"

  template_body = <<STACK
    {
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: Team Server
Metadata:
  'AWS::CloudFormation::Interface':
    ParameterGroups:
      - Label:
          default: Deployment Options
        Parameters:
          - Environment
          - KeyPairName
          - VPCID
          - Subnet1ID
          - RemoteAccessCIDR
          - Owner
    ParameterLabels:
      KeyPairName:
        Default: Key Pair Name
      RemoteAccessCIDR:
        Default: External Access CIDR
      VPCID:
        Default: VPC ID
      Owner:
        Default: MommaTeam....
```

Thank you for any guidance offered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least **two issues** that are apparent:

1. `source = "../../aws_modules/aws-db-event-subscription"` is invalid. There is **no attribute** called `source` in [aws_cloudformation_stack](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cloudformation_stack). You can remove it.
2. Your `template_body` should **not begin** with `{` in:

```
  template_body = <<STACK
    {
```

This is because you are using YAML for your template, not JSON.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. I used the Develop utility in CF to convert my yaml to JSON which made it easier to do.

Comment: @Scouse_Bob No problem. Glad the answer was helpful.